# How to allow a full text search to use more CPU?

Tags: windows-7, performance, cpu, search, intel-core-i7

I'm running 64 bit windows 7. I have the `i7` processor.

I am using NOTEPAD++ to do a full text search through a whole directory of a few thousand text files.

[image]

For some reason when I look at my machine's performance, it shows that I'm hardly utilizing any CPU:

[image]

**How do I force a program to utilize more CPU so that it's faster? The search is taking a long time.**

**Would this information suggest that it might be IO bound?**

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the program isn't already using as much CPU as it can?  (hint: programs are limited to more than just your processor's clock speed; in this case, disk activity/latency would be a good metric to consider).

Comment: @Breakthrough gotcha! thank you. so you are saying an SSD drive might speed this up like crazy right?

Comment: If the process is I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound an SSD would help.

Comment: @Karan would you say that this process is more IO bound?

Comment: Certainly seems that way. You can confirm using something like Resource Monitor.

Comment: @Karan i just added a pic of the Disk activity. would you suggest its probably IO bound?

Comment: You can select notepad++.exe in the list and see the amount of reads it's making. Simply searching through a large number of text files would certainly not tax a CPU like yours.

Comment: Are you running any "memory optimizers" or anything like that? Your system has *way* more free RAM than it should and it's likely that's why I/O is so slow.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz wow! i dont know anything about hardware, but i didnt know ram could slow down IO. btw why do you make an assumption about how much ram i need? im actually running a hadoop cluster on my machine, so that will take up all my ram :)

Comment: It's not about how much RAM you need, it's about whether the system is using the RAM you have or not. For some reason, your system is not using the RAM you have -- notice almost 26GB free. RAM you aren't using is not more useful than RAM you don't have -- neither makes your I/O any faster. (So-called "memory optimizers" make I/O slow by forcing your system to waste lots of memory.)

Comment: im not running many programs.

Comment: Right. So what? You can still use RAM to improve your performance by avoid disk I/O. For some reason, your system isn't doing that. The question is ... why?

Comment: OOOH i see. but how does it know in advance what to suck up into memory?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9514/discussion-between-david-schwartz-and--)